# Fix CSS width-animation issue due to scrollbar hiding in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have animation on my Navbar when I hover over my sections, but when I hid the scrollbar in Chrome the right element's animation broke. There is a bar which width go to 100% when I hover it and 0% when it is not hovering. But the Contact section's bar stay there even after I leave it.

Here are 2 picture of the issue:

[image: Hover]

[image: NO Hover]

See in the 2nd last picture it persist.

The code:

**HTML (it is on a body tag):**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
  scrollbar-width: none;     /*    Firfox scroll hiding*/
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: #e6e6eb;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge scrollbar hiding*/

}


body::-webkit-scrollbar {
/*    Chrome scroll hiding*/
    display: none;
}

/*This is to ensure that the navigation navigate to the correct element*/
.anchor-offset{
  display: block;
  height: 80px; /*same height as header*/
  margin-top: -70px; /*same height as header*/
  visibility: hidden;
}

/*navbar ======================================*/
.nav-container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header
{
    background: #202124;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.nav-logo
{
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

nav
{
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    
    position: relative;
    
}

nav a
{
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: azure;
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block; 
    height: 5px;
    
    background-color: aliceblue;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 0px;
    
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}

nav div:hover {
    color: azure;
}

nav div::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    
    background-color: aliceblue;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav div:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="nav-container">
            <img src="Images/YourLogo.PNG" alt="logo" class="nav-logo">
        
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#About">About</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            
        </div>
        
    </header>
```

How would I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which chrome version are you using. And do you have the same problem in other browsers?

Comment: The snippet does not appear to reproduce the issue? (Chrome 91.0.4472.77, 64 Bit, Win 10)

Comment: Just checked my chrome and I have the same version, i.e. 91.0.4472.77, 64 Bit, Win 10. IT happends on Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but not on Firefox. That is only the partial code so might be because it's only the partial code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making the naimation for from the right instead of the left by adding

```
nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block; 
    height: 5px;
    
    background-color: aliceblue;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 0px;
    right: 0px;   *<- Add this*
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
  scrollbar-width: none;     /*    Firfox scroll hiding*/
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: #e6e6eb;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge scrollbar hiding*/

}


body::-webkit-scrollbar {
/*    Chrome scroll hiding*/
    display: none;
}

/*This is to ensure that the navigation navigate to the correct element*/
.anchor-offset{
  display: block;
  height: 80px; /*same height as header*/
  margin-top: -70px; /*same height as header*/
  visibility: hidden;
}

/*navbar ======================================*/
.nav-container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header
{
    background: #202124;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.nav-logo
{
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

nav
{
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    
    position: relative;
    
}

nav a
{
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: azure;
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block; 
    height: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    
    background-color: aliceblue;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 0px;
    
    transition: opacity .01s linear, width ease-in-out 250ms; 
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

nav div:hover {
    color: azure;
}

nav div::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    
    background-color: aliceblue;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav div:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="nav-container">
            <img src="Images/YourLogo.PNG" alt="logo" class="nav-logo">
        
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#About">About</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            
        </div>
        
    </header>
```

Comment: This takes away the animation

Comment: Adjusted answer and added snippet. Unfortunately answer removes the hoverout animation.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it go from right to left instead of the other way around? Thank you for your answer. This is so annoying.